# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class with eclipselink in tomcat 10

Tags: spring, jpa, tomcat, eclipselink, tomcat10

Im trying to upgrade spring web app to tomcat 10 for the upgrade im using apache jakarta migration tool. the application got successfully migrated using this tool but when i run the application in tomcat 10 im facing following issue

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class
please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.

and tables are not being created in the database.

when i run same application in tomcat 9 the tables are being created and i dont face any exception there.

i cant able to figure what is the problem in tomcat 10 even after using migration tool.

Comment: Spring doesn't support Tomcat 10 nor Jakarta so this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 5 does not work with Tomcat 10 due to changes in Tomcat packages from
javax
to
jakarta.